# $G\cong G/H\times H$ measurably

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact abelian group, $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$.

Suppose that both $G,H$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Haar measure. Why is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to $G/H\times H$ as measure spaces? (i.e there exists a measurable map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H\times H$ that is one to one and onto up to a set of measure zero).

Comment: Answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870255/is-there-a-borel-measurable-projection-to-a-closed-subgroup/2874246#2874246